# Editing text in PyCharm

Tags: python, fonts, formatting, pycharm, editing

I've started using PyCharm 2 this year and it's working well for me, the only thing is that when I add comments in, it all sort of gets lost in the amounts of code.

Is there a way to add any text formatting to only certain parts of my programs? Like increasing the font of the comments that separate different practice questions, or even just bolding some of my comments to make the sections stand out more?

I know you can change the text for the entire file, but I want some diversity so it's a bit easier for other people (and sometimes myself) to read.

Comment: By default comments should be grey colored. You can configure the coloring of different elements in Preferences.

Comment: @Barmar yes they are grey for me. Does configuring the colours of different elements change the colours for all comments I make?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Preferences->Editing->Color Scheme**. From there you can change the way all the different types of program elements are displayed. You can use colors, bold, and italic to highlight things differently. I don't think you can assign different fonts or sizes, though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **Color scheme**

Comments are under "Language Defaults"